# How to connect swiper js to astro.build and make it a component?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

How to connect swiper js to astro.build and make it a component? Without using React

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve that with a  after the carousel element, not in the frontMatter but at the following of the code inside my component ProjectSlider.astro.
The script should begin with these 4 lines which makes the SwiperJS slider registered and available.
You can see it here in the Swiper Docs : https://swiperjs.com/element#install--register-from-npm
Here is my example :

```
---
// Your frontMatter here
---

<!-- ProjectSlider.astro -->
<section id="ProjectSlider" class="swiper">
    <ul class="swiper-wrapper" data-cursor="swipe">
        {
            slides.map((slide) => (
                <li class="swiper-slide">
                    // Your Card here
                </li>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
</section>

<script>

    import 'swiper/css';
    import Swiper from 'swiper';
    import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
    register();

    const swiper = new Swiper('#ProjectSlider', {
        // Setup
        loop: false,
        lazy: true,
        autoplay: false,
        grabCursor: false,
        mousewheel: false,
    });

</script>
<!-- /ProjectSlider.astro -->
```